# Excel 2010 Microsoft forms error Could not load some objects because they are not available on this machine

Tags: excel, vba, 64-bit, ms-office, userform

I have office 2010 64 bit and I am trying to open a excel file with a userform in it that was made in office 32 bit. I get this error "Excel 2010 Microsoft forms error Could not load some objects because they are not available on this machine". then the files closes

When I click the help button it says "Compile error in hidden module: module name "

Is there there a way I can fix this so that I can open this file or files like this if this is a common issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you should be able to open the file even though it generates a compile error. Can you open the file with macro's disabled? (just rename the file so Excel does not know you opened it before)

If so, then go to the VBA editor and check Tools, References. Note the ones markes MISSING. I bet one is something like "Common Controls". If you open the userforms you should have some empty spaces where a control used to be, those are the incompatible ones.

Comment: Yes I disabled macros and entered the file but I don't see any missing references

Comment: I checked the userform and there seems to be  empty spaces where the date boxes are supposed to be.

Comment: If those are date time picker boxes then you'll have to re-create them yourself. LIke this one: https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50/calendar-control-class